# Python Tkinter, how to disable a button in a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have seen many explanations of how to turn an enabled button disabled but not when classes are involved. The error here is in the line 'button_1.config...' and the error message is that button_1 is not defined. I think this is because it is in a different method but im not sure how to disable a button from a different method. any help is appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *

class menu:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        button_1 = Button(self.master, text = 'test', command = self.correct).pack()
    def correct(self):
        button_1.config(state = DISABLED)

def window():
    root = Tk()
    menu(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window()
```

Answer (score 1):

The button needs to be an instance variable, if you're accessing it between methods in the class. Just add `self.` in front of it. It's also going to need to be `packed` on a separate line, otherwise the instance variable `self.button_1` will return None:

```
class menu:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.button_1 = Button(self.master, text = 'test', command = self.correct)
        self.button_1.pack()
    def correct(self):
        self.button_1.config(state = DISABLED)
```